# Unable to switch on wi fi on acer aspire ES 15 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, rfkill

I have a dual boot Acer Aspire ES 15 with ubuntu 16.04 and windows7. sometimes i am not able switch on wifi in ubuntu while wifi works perfectly in windows 7. I have to log into windows and then come back to ubuntu for wifi to be start getting connected.

The hardware key for wifi Fn+F3 is not working to in ubuntu.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565    Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0642]
  Kernel driver in use: ath9k
  Kernel modules: ath9k

$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes

1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no

2: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry for the late reply. The output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 command is added

Comment: You can try to blacklist `acer_wmi`.